# nodejs, heroku, mongoose and mlab

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I'm looking for a pointer than an accurate answer for this question cause I think there can be a million things wrong and I'm not sure which direction to go.

I'm hosting a MongoDb database with mLab and trying to deploy with heroku.  I can access the Login/Register Page (so the app is deployed properly) but I can't register myself as a user (database not authenticating/working).

Any ideas or pointers?

I have attached the snippet for Mongo URL and the Heroku log.

```js
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

var dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_UI || "mongodb://user:pass@ds135552.mlab.com:35552/kb"
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
```

```html
2017-06-26T16:25:32.756082+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 0.293 ms - -
2017-06-26T16:25:32.709238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/login" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=037cfd56-559d-475b-a704-c51807e81a18 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:25:32.749139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/style.css" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=1815b432-963a-46fa-b413-ee2696f479d0 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:25:38.844267+00:00 app[web.1]: The username from models is [object Object]
2017-06-26T16:26:08.840785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/auth/login" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=8cf5fcea-d8a9-4179-9259-66c88e7b93f0 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:26:08.838741+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /auth/login - - ms - -
2017-06-26T16:29:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user leeraj42@gmail.com
2017-06-26T16:29:46.016726+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b29758ba by user leeraj42@gmail.com
2017-06-26T16:29:46.016726+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user leeraj42@gmail.com
2017-06-26T16:29:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-06-26T16:29:46.667314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-06-26T16:29:46.668905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-06-26T16:29:47.167601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-06-26T16:29:47.330327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-06-26T16:29:49.328038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-06-26T16:29:52.207453+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-06-26T16:29:52.207466+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-06-26T16:29:52.207467+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-06-26T16:29:52.252423+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongoose connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
2017-06-26T16:29:52.219970+00:00 app[web.1]: Node app is running on port 19229
2017-06-26T16:29:53.037931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-26T16:30:17.280590+00:00 app[web.1]: The username from models is [object Object]
2017-06-26T16:30:47.130455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/auth/login" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=5ec816a1-88c4-44bd-8b74-4a59c96d12f7 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:47.139053+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /auth/login - - ms - -
2017-06-26T16:30:54.381052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/login" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=ac4b246e-d37b-46ab-9d48-d7a88943f01b fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=49ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:54.450202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=879ce31e-45b4-4987-8589-0f89e84fb53f fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=192030 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:54.290356+00:00 app[web.1]: login failed!
2017-06-26T16:30:54.292182+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 302 14.063 ms - 66
2017-06-26T16:30:54.383895+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /auth/login 304 46.887 ms - -
2017-06-26T16:30:54.451158+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 200 8.943 ms - 191738
2017-06-26T16:30:54.453710+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 3.958 ms - 6842
2017-06-26T16:30:54.288549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=9f787e71-a24f-40ba-8a95-5ee3b23a4af6 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=302 bytes=396 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:54.451052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/style.css" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=8c0feb6a-0fb8-4db4-bae4-e69bcf69bfa3 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=7131 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:56.577040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/style.css" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=dd8b0e20-801e-4a34-b3e1-374d1b5181d0 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:56.524147+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /auth/register 304 4.187 ms - -
2017-06-26T16:30:56.577481+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 1.431 ms - -
2017-06-26T16:30:56.580005+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.711 ms - -
2017-06-26T16:30:56.574164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=f4b0997d-fba8-4f80-b458-6c841eac780f fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:30:56.521418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/register" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=aafe3bf3-ed8f-4956-8fe8-8754ef8df17f fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2017-06-26T16:31:37.708988+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /auth/register - - ms - -
2017-06-26T16:31:37.696409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/auth/register" host=saleshubkb.herokuapp.com request_id=af196d12-51f8-4a6b-96f2-b04a250a0c30 fwd="158.106.103.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: Try reaching out to support@mlab.com; they should be able to provide more detailed information about what is causing the failed authentication. (Full disclosure: I work for mLab.)

Comment: I think it was a typo, but you should replace process.env.MONGOLAB_UI with process.env.MONGOLAB_URI (missing an R) and also you could try to connect from your machine using mongo shell or any other way, perhaps it could give a hint of what is happening.

Comment: cool cool. thanks a lot Adam and andreesk!